# How to make two isset-functions that work together in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, isset

How to make two if-functions that work together in PHP?

In my code i have different buttons that allow the user to sort the way he wants to sort the rows from the database, they click a button, and the sql-statement changes like this:

```
        if (isset($_GET['ASC'])){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM merke JOIN modell ON merke.idmerke=modell.merke_idmerke JOIN modell_has_personer ON modell.idmodell=modell_has_personer.modell_idmodell JOIN personer ON modell_has_personer.personer_idpersoner=personer.idpersoner ORDER BY merkenavn ASC";}
        else if (isset($_GET['aar'])){$sql = "SELECT * FROM merke JOIN modell ON merke.idmerke=modell.merke_idmerke JOIN modell_has_personer ON modell.idmodell=modell_has_personer.modell_idmodell JOIN personer ON modell_has_personer.personer_idpersoner=personer.idpersoner ORDER BY aar ASC";} 
            else {$sql = "SELECT * FROM merke JOIN modell ON merke.idmerke=modell.merke_idmerke JOIN modell_has_personer ON modell.idmodell=modell_has_personer.modell_idmodell JOIN personer ON modell_has_personer.personer_idpersoner=personer.idpersoner ORDER BY merkenavn DESC";}
        $resultat =  $kobling->query($sql);
```

Here ASC and aar are different buttons that the user can click on, and when he does, the sql-statement changes.

This works well, but then i wanted to implement an option for the user to sort out rows that doesnt start with the letters that the user chooses like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['go'])){ $ja = $_GET["ja"]; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM merke JOIN modell ON merke.idmerke=modell.merke_idmerke JOIN modell_has_personer ON modell.idmodell=modell_has_personer.modell_idmodell JOIN personer ON modell_has_personer.personer_idpersoner=personer.idpersoner WHERE merkenavn LIKE '$ja%'";}
```

Here  $ja  is the variable for what letter(s) the rows must start on.

My problem her is this: How to i combine these to so that if the user clicks on a button to sort the rows but also wants to sort out rows by first letter(s) both of them happen?

Comment: You should learn to use parameterized queries.

Comment: [Didn't you ask this already?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60357066/1415724) You also were asked something in a comment but never responded. So for me, what you posted here is a repost and both are unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Create the WHERE part of the query (`$whr_sql`) first, and then add to your `$sql`

```
if (isset($_GET['go'])){ $ja = $_GET["ja"]; 
    $whr_sql = " WHERE merkenavn LIKE '$ja%' ";
}else{
    $whr_sql = " ";
}

if (isset($_GET['ASC'])){$sql = "SELECT * FROM merke JOIN modell ON merke.idmerke=modell.merke_idmerke JOIN modell_has_personer ON modell.idmodell=modell_has_personer.modell_idmodell JOIN personer ON modell_has_personer.personer_idpersoner=personer.idpersoner".$whr_sql."ORDER BY merkenavn ASC";}
else if (isset($_GET['aar'])){$sql = "SELECT * FROM merke JOIN modell ON merke.idmerke=modell.merke_idmerke JOIN modell_has_personer ON modell.idmodell=modell_has_personer.modell_idmodell JOIN personer ON modell_has_personer.personer_idpersoner=personer.idpersoner".$whr_sql."ORDER BY aar ASC";} 
else {$sql = "SELECT * FROM merke JOIN modell ON merke.idmerke=modell.merke_idmerke JOIN modell_has_personer ON modell.idmodell=modell_has_personer.modell_idmodell JOIN personer ON modell_has_personer.personer_idpersoner=personer.idpersoner".$whr_sql."ORDER BY merkenavn DESC";}

$resultat =  $kobling->query($sql);
```